# Why does 1/2 in c = -2010232232?

Tags: c, floating-point, double

I have a very simple C program.

```
int main(void){

  double sum = 1/2;

  printf("%d\n", sum);

  return 0;

}
```

Why does it return a number like "-2030243223"?

And why does this number change every time I run the program?

I've tried using int's and float's but I can't seem to get the output to be 0.5!?

Comment: Use 1.0/2 instead of 1/2. Also, "%d" is for integers.

Comment: @devnull, presumably that's because it's lunchtime and folk are starting to tire of Grand Theft Auto 5.

Answer (score 11):

Use `%f` to print a `double`, not `%d`. The latter causes **undefined behavior**.

Also the expression `1/2` uses integer division which yields `0`, so to get `.5`, use `1/2.` (note trailing period).

Finally, to actually get `.5` instead of something like `0.500000`, specify the precision:

```
printf("%.1f\n", sum);
```

Answer (score 5):

You're passing an [IEEE floating-point number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) to `printf`, but telling it it's an integer.

Change

```
printf("%d\n", sum);
```

to

```
printf("%f\n", sum);
```

As noted in other comments, you probably also want to do floating-point division rather than integer division. `1/2` is zero; you're dividing two integers, so the result is an integer (yes, even though you're about to assign it into a floating-point variable -- each expression's type is determined in isolation) and it has to discard the remainder. You probably want `1.0/2` instead; if either term is a float, then the result is a float, so you'll get 0.5.

Comment: Then it just returns 0.00000?

Comment: Other comments already covered that, but I've edited to explain why you're getting zero and what you probably want to do about it.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to print a double to an Integer. (%d).

Even though they both are numbers, internally there are huge differences, for example, memory ones.

Comment: Trying to print a double _as if it were_ an integer.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to print a double as an int.  Try using:

```
printf("%g\n");
```

Also, you will want to make you initial division 1.0/2.0 or else you will get 0.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int main(void){

  double sum = 1.0/2.0;

  printf("%10.3f\n", sum);

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: Providing new working code does not answer the question about why the old code behaved as it did or explain what was wrong with the old code.

Comment: @duffymo - it would be a *better* answer if it explained what the fix was.

Comment: Better than a comment.  I don't always have time or inclination to do all that I'd like.  Why don't you cite answers that don't provide code?  I think it's helpful and leaves the door open for introspection and learning.

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of issues with your code

```
int main(void){
  // you need to divide a double by a double, not two ints
  double sum = 1.0/2.0; 
  // %d is for int, not doubles. You use %f in the case of printing a double
  printf("%f\n", sum); 
  return 0;

}
```

Now if you really want to print the variable as an int, you can cast the variable `sum` as an int by doing `printf("%d\n", (int)sum);`, but you'll have a rounding issue.

Comment: `printf("%f\n", (int)sum);` is the opposite mistake, passing an `int` for a `double` specifier. Also, this answer quotes out-of-context an answer explaining a specific situation. It may have been okay to indicate that an `int` is four bytes in that specific situation, but we should not give the impression that is always the case.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
printf("%f\n", sum);
```

%d is a placeholder for integer, maybe the address of sum has been printed out^^

Comment: Since the behavior is undefined, anything may happen, but I can't think of a reason that `&sum` would be printed. More likely, there's an alignment issue and `printf` reads garbage from the stack.

Answer (score 0):

The bad format can't be the whole answer, because:

- With OP's code, the `double` should be zero, stored as 0x0000000000000000, which couldn't show as "-2030243223" (0x86FCF269).
- OP says this value changes all the time.

So there must be something else, such as the fact that the header is missing: I guess the compiler doesn't know `printf` is a variadic function, and tries to pass the argument through floating-point registers.

`printf`, being a variadic function, probably attempts to read its input value from the stack, hence garbage.

Comment: The fact that `printf` has a variable argument list does not require its parameters to be passed on the stack in a way that necessarily puts a `double` in the same place as an `int`. The platform application binary interface may have rules that, when the next argument is a `double`, bytes are to be skipped so that the argument is aligned to a multiple of eight bytes. Then attempting to read an `int` argument when a `double` was passed would read the uncontrolled bytes that were skipped.

Comment: Another possibility is for the ABI to specify that the first floating-point argument is passed through a floating-point only register. This can be verified by compiling the program `int printf(const char *, ...); void f(int x) { printf("%d", x+1); printf("%f", (double)x); }` with the command `gcc -m64 -O -S` on x86-64. In this case, the mismatch between format and arguments mean that an integer register (e.g. `%esi`) is consumed inside `printf()` that was not set to any particular value by the caller.

Comment: The above comment applies regardless of whether the function is variadic, because a restriction for variadic functions is completely unnecessary. `printf()` fetches its first floating-point argument from the appropriate floating-point register when the format first indicates a floating-point format. Why would arguments have to be passed on the stack?

Comment: @PascalCuoq Uhm, because variadic functions are given a pointer thereto? It's even specified in some ABIs (such as Windows's on x86-64) that explicitly use registers for all other functions!

Comment: I didn't know that Windows' ABI worked this way. Here is the assembly of the short program I recommended compiling, when compiled on Mac OS X (x86-64): http://pastebin.com/FUBajGBZ . It shows that `printf("%d", int_expr)` uses `%esi` and `printf("%f", double_expr)` uses `%xmm0`. One can infer that, on Mac OS X x86-64, `printf("%d", double_expr)` prints the contents of a `%esi` register that didn't know it was going to be printed.